# Formatting items in a ttk::treeview for display

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

Is there a way to influence the rendering of items in a ttk::treeview? I would e.g. like to internally store sizes as plain numbers in bytes but display them formatted in kB or MB.

So far I'm storing the data twice, once in a dictionary as raw data and once in the ttk::treeview in a pretty-printed format, however that is quite ugly as I need extra code in order to keep the ttk::treeview in sync.

Answer (score 0):

The item label and data value strings are the strings that are rendered.

However, you could add the raw data to an extra column which is not shown (don't list it in `-displaycolumns`).